# Signalr StatusCode 500 VS 2017

Tags: signalr, signalr.client, visual-studio-2017

I have a Class library that I am trying to hook to my web's Signlar

```
SiteConnection = new HubConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SignalrSite"]){ Credentials = Credentials.NetworkCredential }; 
SiteHub = SiteConnection .CreateHubProxy("SiteHub "); 
SiteConnection.Start().Wait();
```

In VS 2015 This works fine.

in 2017 I get...

> StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1,
>   Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Transfer-Encoding:
>   chunked X-SourceFiles:
>   =?UTF-8?B?QzpcRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnRcRUlNXEJPTSBQb3J0YWxcTWFpblxCb20uUG9ydGFsLldlYlxzaWduYWxyXG5lZ290aWF0ZQ==?=
>   Persistent-Auth: false Cache-Control: private Date: Tue, 07 Mar 2017
>   23:33:46 GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this. Visual Studio must be ran as administrator.